# How to remove an xml tag that just contains a number using Groovy

Tags: regex, xml, groovy

I have the following XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<0>
    <user>
        <fname>bob</fname>
        <lname>marley</lname>
        <age>30</age>
    </user>
</0>
<1>
    <user>
        <fname>john</fname>
        <lname>lennon</lname>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
</1>
<2>
    <user>
        <fname>phil</fname>
        <lname>smith</lname>
        <age>40</age>
    </user>
</2>
```

I would like to end up with just the users .... like so ...

```
    <user>
        <fname>bob</fname>
        <lname>marley</lname>
        <age>30</age?
    </user>
    <user>
        <fname>john</fname>
        <lname>lennon</lname>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <fname>phil</fname>
        <lname>smith</lname>
        <age>40</age>
    </user>
```

I have already used a regular expression to get rid of the XML declaration line ... but now I need to remove the integer tags and get just the USER tags

This is what I have so far. I am getting tripped up on the regular expression part .. ( I think!)

```
String x1 = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<0>
    <user>
        <fname>bob</fname>
        <lname>marley</lname>
        <age>30</age>
    </user>
</0>
<1>
    <user>
        <fname>john</fname>
        <lname>lennon</lname>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
</1>
<2>
    <user>
        <fname>phil</fname>
        <lname>smith</lname>
        <age>40</age>
    </user>
</2>
'''

import java.util.regex.Pattern

//remove the XML declaration
String x2 = x1.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();

//grab the opening XML tag --- not quite sure how to insert dynamic REGEX here
String openingNumberTag = "<" + "[0-9]+" + ">";

//grab the closing XML tag --- not quite sure how to insert dynamic REGEX here
String closingNumberTag = "</" + "[0-9]+" + ">";

//Now iterate through the XML string and remove the number tags
if (x2.matches(openingNumberTag))
{
    //remove it somehow;                     
}
if (x2.matches(closingNumberTag))
{
    //remove it somehow;                     
}

//Print the final XML string with just the USER tags
println(x2);
```

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Whoever "invented" this XML should be ashamed.

Comment: I don't even think that is valid xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it thusly ...

```
String x1 = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<0>
    <user>
        <fname>bob</fname>
        <lname>marley</lname>
        <age>30</age>
    </user>
</0>
<1>
    <user>
        <fname>john</fname>
        <lname>lennon</lname>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
</1>
<2>
    <user>
        <fname>phil</fname>
        <lname>smith</lname>
        <age>40</age>
    </user>
</2>
'''

import java.util.regex.Pattern

//remove the XML declaration
String x2 = x1.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
String x3 = x2.replaceAll("<[0-9]+>", "").trim();
String x4 = x3.replaceAll("</[0-9]+>", "").trim();


println(x4);
```